# Why is app incompatible with my phone?

Tags: 8.1, apps, nokia-lumia-920, compatibility

Why is [Work Item Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/work-item-studio/9wzdncrfjbgz) app incompatible with my Lumia 920? OS version is Lumia Denim 8.10.14234.375. Is there any way to install this app. In history i have installed this app but now i can't.

Answer (score 1):

**In the phone**

Check that the date and time of the phone are correct.

1. Select **Settings**> **Date / Time & Language**> **Date & Time**
   (Lumia with Windows Phone 8: **Settings**> **Date & Time**).
2. Set **Set date and time automatically to Off** and manually set the
   current date, time, and time zone.

Go to the Store and check if there are any unsuccessful download apps or games, cancel all pending downloads, restart your phone, and then manually search for app or game updates in the Store. Keep your phone connected to a charger and a Wi-Fi network while looking for app updates.

1. Select **Store**> **Menu**> **Downloads and Updates** (Lumia with
   Windows Phone 8: **Store**> ...> **Download**) or tap the icon that
   indicates the number of pending downloads.
2. If an error is displayed, view details, and then touch for more
   information. To delete an app from the queue, touch the app and
   touch **X** to stop the download and remove it from the queue. Lumia
   with Windows Phone 8: If Attention message appears, touch for more
   information. To delete an app from the queue, hold down and then
   select **Cancel download**.
3. Lumia with Windows 10: Check that there is no pending software
   update in your phone, going to **Settings**> **Upgrade & Security**>
   **Updates**.
4. Restart your phone and start manual search for app updates. Go to
   **Store**> **Menu**> **Downloads and Updates** (Lumia with Windows Phone 8: **Store**> ...> **Settings**, touch **Search Updates**). At
   the bottom of the screen you will see **Check for Updates**. After
   checking for updates, select **Update All** at the top of the
   screen.
5. Keep your phone connected to a charger and a Wi-Fi network and wait
   for the download of app updates.

Comment: I have switched timezone to settings to manual, restarted phone, no store and system updates but app is still shown as incompatible.

Comment: Try to installing the app via PC:  1. Access Windows Phone Store from PC  2. Search your app and click on the "Download and install manually" item on the sidebar, under the app's info  3. Connect your Windows Phone 8.1 device to your PC via USB cable and then move (or copy) the downloaded XAP to the "download" folder in your phone's memory  4. Unplug the device from the PC and open the client for access to the Windows Phone Store and from the options (the three dots) select the item "install local apps"  5. Select the downloaded app and start the installation process.

Comment: I have no `install local apps` is store. There are only my apps, downloads and settings.